# Sonata AdminBundle with a Child cannot be rendered

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig, sonata-admin

Im trying to configure the Sonata AdminBundle. Its a very interesting bundle with many functionalities however it is not straightforward to use. I have a Post entity so I can tweak the posts, as in the doc manual. I want to implement a child Admin, for the comments of each post (a Many to One relationship). I implemented it as a service and a __toString() method for the variable however I get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string")
>   in SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:CRUD:list_orm_many_to_one.html.twig at
>   line 17.

I do not understand why not it could not be converted to a string the content of the ManyToOne variable. Any help is appreciated here.

Here is the Post entity code:

```
<?php

namespace Blog\BlogBundle\Entity;

class Post

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $comments;

/**
* Construct DateTime and Comments Array
*/
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();

    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->comments;
}

Other private and setters and getters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->comments;
}
```

from your Post entity and add it to your comments entity but change $this->comments to the field used for the body of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

IMO :

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function __toString()
 {
     return $this->comments;
 }
```

This method must return a string and not an array collection

Comment: Because the __toString() method must be into your Comment Entity and not on Post.

Comment: I already have __toString() implemented on both Post and Comment entity and still get the very same error, even if I have just the method on the comment entity. Any other suggestions please¿?